# How can I get Soap request and response xml through Soap server

Tags: php, soap

Is there any way to get SOAP request and response through SOAP server. I know that I can get it via SOAP client?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The *entire* point of a SOAP server is to listen for requests and send responses (while the entire point of a SOAP client is to make requests and listen to responses). Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can manage the request and response xml in database. This is requirement of one of my client.

Comment: That makes even less sense. Databases are used to store data. Requests and responses are managed by HTTP servers and clients.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get the request xml on my SOAP server, we can get it via following line:-
file_get_contents('php://input')
This provide us the Raw POST data.
But still struggling with response xml.Hope to find a solution for that too.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, a SOAP call is just http.

To get the raw SOAP XML request, use the PHP function `http_get_request_body()` or use the `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']` variable.

To get the XML response, you can capture it after you do `$soapServer->handle();` with `$xml = ob_get_contents();` much the same way as you would grab the output of a web page.